# Using different DS layouts with the Context module

Tags: theming, 6, display-suite

I have build a "build mode" called "anonimus_profile" in admin/build/ds/modules/nd/buildmodes.

I went to admin/build/ds/layout/profile2/anomimos_profile, and configured the fields.
I enabled the Context module, and configured the options.

The conditions are the following ones:

- Node type: profile2
- User role: anonymous user

The reactions are the following ones:

- Nd build-modes: Anónimos profile

I saved the context, and cleared the cache, but the anonymous user doesn't see anything different.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: may be you would like to try Page manger it goes with ctools and uses panels (here is some [description](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager-part-1-overview)).

Comment: Thanks ijujym.
I'm with page manager, it's easy, but The idea is use display suit. I'd like to build new ways of works.